# Dynamic reconfigure and parameter namespaces in octomap_server

Tags: ros, parameters, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm improving the reconfigure server of the `octomap_server` package. However, I am facing the problem that some of the parameters have a name space: `sensor_model/max_range` for instance. In the reconfigure callback, this is not a huge problem as I added the following line to the `.cfg` file:

```
gen.add("max_range", double_t, 0, "Sensor maximum range", -1.0, -1.0, 100)
```

And in the reconfigure callback:

```
m_maxRange = config.max_range;
```

Therefore I can work with the reconfigure server as usual. However, if I load any parameter with rosparam or through a launch file, the loaded value will not match with the dynamic reconfigure value. Is there any way to properly *link*  the `max_range` parameter of the `.cfg` to the corresponding name in the parameter server, `sensor_model/max_range`?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210400/dynamic-reconfigure-and-parameter-namespaces-in-octomap_server/) by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1305 on 2015-06-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer to http://answers.ros.org/question/57498/notify-changes-to-dynamic_reconfigure/ has a line (and the context is useful also, but this is the key thing I assume causes the values as seen in rqt_dynamic_configure or elsewhere to be changed):

```
    dynamic_reconfigure_server.updateConfig(config);
```

**Update**

This is something I just tried in python that didn't require the node hosting the server to call its own set_parameters service (and thus requiring multiple threads and mutex protection)

```
    x = rospy.get_param("z", 0.0)
    y = rospy.get_param("z", 0.0)
    self.srv.update_configuration({\
            "x":x,
            "y":y,
            })
```

This is sort of shown in one tutorial, but the client is using it rather than going direct on the server.
I'd like to figure out how to do this in C++ now.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2015-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-06-19**:
Thank you for the info. I will take a look at this. However, it is a bit disappointing that dynamic reconfigure cannot take into account such parameter names.

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-06-19**:
So it is working now, but interestingly I did not add the suggested line. It just worked, now the initial values match the configuration. Thank you anyway!

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-07-09**:
Recently I wanted to have params override the dynamic reconfigure .cfg defaults, I had to make my node multi-threaded with AsyncSpinner (can't call a service provided by the same single thread node, the call methods block instead of calling back).  If you have a better way I'd like to know about it.

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-07-10**:
I just loaded the param file with `rosparam` and it overrode the .cfg defaults. It wasn't working at the beginning but then it worked, with no important changes I would say.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-07-16**:
I tried using regular params in the launch file for my node, but they didn't override the cfg values, so I'm using the above (ugly) method now.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-07-20**:
I've since gotten updateConfig working and I run that after getting the params in my constructor, it doesn't require multiple threads.